# How do I solve this access error from hal config provider appengine?

Tags: spinnaker

I get get an error when run the command blow. Which resources is that I am denied access to? How to I get access to these resources?

> Steins-MacBook-Pro-2:Spinnaker stein$ hal config provider appengine
> account add my-appengine-account --project $GCP-PROJECT-ID
> --write-permissions=[]
>
> - Get current deployment   Success WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal reflective access by
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil
>   (file:/opt/halyard/lib/jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar) to constructor
>   java.lang.Void() WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the
>   maintainers of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil WARNING:
>   Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal
>   reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations
>   will be denied in a future release
>
> - Add the my-appengine-account account   Failure Problems in default.provider.appengine.my-appengine-account: ! ERROR Failed to
>   connect to appengine Admin API: 403 Forbidden {   "code" : 403,
>   "errors" : [ {
>   "domain" : "global",
>   "message" : "The caller does not have permission",
>   "reason" : "forbidden"   } ],   "message" : "The caller does not have permission",   "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED" }.

- Failed to add account my-appengine-account for provider   appengine. Steins-MacBook-Pro-2:Spinnaker stein$ hal config provider appengine account list

- Get current deployment   Success
- Get the appengine provider   Success Problems in default.provider.appengine:

- WARNING Provider appengine is enabled, but no accounts have been   configured.

- No configured accounts for appengine.

Answer (score 0):

WHat was missing was the right data in $GCP_PROJECT-ID
I change the $GCP_PROJECT-ID to  project-235906 and then it is working